# ¿Cómo poner una etiqueta de datos en un ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Realicé el siguiente gráfico de barras:

```
ggplot(data = notificados_prov_2023) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = reorder(Provincia, desc(tasa)), 
                         y = tasa), stat="identity", fill = "#88DAEE") + 
  labs(x="Provincia de residencia", y="Tasa de notificación c/ 100.000 hab", 
       title="Tasa de notificación de coqueluche cada 100.000 habitantes según provincia de residencia. Año 2023. Argentina.") +
  theme_classic()+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=12, face='bold'), 
                        plot.caption = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0), 
                        axis.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
                        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1), 
                        legend.position = "top")+scale_fill_jama() + 
  ylim(0,130)
```

Y no logro ponerle etiquetas de datos, que tendrían que ser los números de la columna "tasa" del df "notificados_prov_2023". Intenté con el siguiente código sin resultados. Tampoco con stat="identity".

```
geom_text(aes(label = notificados_prov_2023$tasa), 
              vjust = -1, colour = "black", size =  3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema mas visible (sin datos de ejemplo no puedo profundizar mucho) es que  el `geom_text()` requiere mapear, además de la etiqueta, las coordenada `x` e `y` que no las estarías definiendo. Si lo haces en el `geom_bar()` pero haciéndolo a nivel de `geom` esta configuración no la hereda ninguno de los otros `geom`. Tienes dos alternativas:

#### Definir la estética a nivel del gráfico:

```
ggplot(data = notificados_prov_2023,
       mapping = aes(x = reorder(Provincia, desc(tasa))))
```

Y luego simplemente:

```
geom_text(aes(label = tasa), 
          vjust = -1, colour = "black", size =  3)
```

Y seria recomendable quitar el `aes()` del `geom_bar()` para permitir que use el global del gráfico. **Nota**: tené en cuenta que no es lo mismo hacer `notificados_prov_2023$tasa` que simplemente `tasa`.

#### Definirla a nivel del `geom`:

Esto sería repetir el `aes` del `geom_bar()`:

```
geom_text(mapping = aes(x = reorder(Provincia, desc(tasa)), 
                        y = tasa,
                        label = tasa), 
          vjust = -1, colour = "black", size =  3)
```

En este ejemplo, no tiene sentido hacer esto, al usar siempre el mismo "mapeo" estetico, es preferible definirlo a nivel global.